# ttk checkbutton is not deselected by default

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, tkinter.checkbutton, ttkwidgets

[Please kick here to see the current output and expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBHb0.jpg)

I have a simple python program where i want to deselect the checkbutton by default. I want to see it the same way as when a user unchecks a tick box. Please let me know how to achieve it.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def urgentReq():
    global box
    state = box.state()
    if(box.instate(['selected'])):        
        print ("--> Urgent: ",state)
    else:
        print ("--> Not Urgent:",state)

gui = Tk()
gui.title("GUI")
gui.geometry('200x150')

box = ttk.Checkbutton(gui, text ='Urgent Request', command=lambda: urgentReq())
box.grid(column=1, row=4, pady=40, sticky="N")
#write something here to unselect the box by default
```

Comment: When I run your code the `Checkbutton` *is* unselected initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the initial state of the CheckButton = `('alternate',)`.

There is a workaround I found here: [tkk checkbutton appears when loaded up with black box in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43030219/tkk-checkbutton-appears-when-loaded-up-with-black-box-in-it). If you apply it to your code like this, it seems to work:

```
checkVar = IntVar()
box = ttk.Checkbutton(gui, text ='Urgent Request', command=lambda: urgentReq(), variable=checkVar)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
box.state(['!alternate'])  #box appear unchecked
box.state(['selected'])  #box appear checked
```

Comment: `box.state(['!alternate'])` solved by problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use the .invoke() method, but from what I read elsewhere is will also call the command, if one is associated. The instance I was trying to use this, my check button didn't have a command as a parameter, so this worked perfectly for me.

Hope this helps and good luck!