# ttk checkbutton appears when loaded up with black box in it

Tags: python, class, tkinter, ttk

taken from: [tkk checkbutton appears when loaded up with black box in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43030219/tkk-checkbutton-appears-when-loaded-up-with-black-box-in-it/51715280#51715280?newreg=f0a0c35ac5d04dd8879b02cb59bfde07)

the provided solution works well with one checkbutton

```
import tkinter as Tk
from tkinter import IntVar
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Checkbutton
class TestGui(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.var1 = IntVar()
        self.var1.set(1)
        button = Checkbutton(parent,
            text="Pick me, pick me!",
            variable=self.var1)        # note difference here
        button.grid()

root = Tk.Tk()
app = TestGui(root)
root.mainloop()
```

but when I create multiple buttons using a loop in my class, this only works for the last button.

Comment: So you've shown us code that works, and not the code that actually exhibits the problem - seriously???  I'm going to take a wild guess here, and say that you probably aren't saving all of the individual `IntVar`s that are attached to the buttons (in a list, perhaps).

Comment: Have you tried using `var1` instead of `self.var1`? Also, the point of providing your code is to _demonstrate your problem_. If you only provide code that works, it makes it harder for us to help you. Please provide a [example] that _demonstrates the problem_. See [ask] and the [help] for more information on asking good questions.

Comment: im sorry jason , didn't mean to offend your honour. I'm new here, I'll improve. 

  thank u for the nice information guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cant really explain why, but I figured it out.

doesnt work(using list):

```
    varss = []
    for n in range (2):
        date = datetime.today() + timedelta(days=n)
        day = datetime.strftime(date, "%d.%m.%y")
        for h in range(24):

            date = date.replace(hour=h,minute=0)
            txt_date = datetime.strftime(date,"%H:%M")
            var = IntVar()
            c = ttk.Checkbutton(tour_frame,text = txt_date,variable = var)
            var.set(1)
            c.grid(column = n , row = h + 1)
            varss.append(var)
```

does work(using list of dicts):

```
    l= []
    for n in range (2):
        date = datetime.today() + timedelta(days=n)
        day = datetime.strftime(date, "%d.%m.%y")
        for h in range(24):

            date = date.replace(hour=h,minute=0)
            txt_date = datetime.strftime(date,"%H:%M")
            var = IntVar()
            c = ttk.Checkbutton(tour_frame,text = txt_date,variable = var)
            var.set(1)
            c.grid(column = n , row = h + 1)
            l.append(dict(datetime = date.replace(hour = h,minute=0,second=False,microsecond=False),value = var ))
```